# Having trouble setting up Unity 5 with android sdk on mac

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to create a mobile game for android through unity and running into some difficulties.

When watching tutorials and googling this is what is shown is that it is navigated to through the *Preferences > External Tools*. But there is no option there for me.

Here is a comparison side by side of how guides say it should look vs how it looks for me.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how it looks on Mac, but on Windows you should opt-in Android Build Support when you installing Unity.

[image: unity installer]

Comment: Thank you! In the mac download it doesn't auto select the Android Build Support, so that's why the option never appeared. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

## Mac unity android sdk path setting

If you have Android Studio installed.
The path for SDK is “/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk”.

But sometimes the “Library” folder is hidden.
To see the hidden files, follow the link: http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/
Or follow the steps below
* Open Terminal found in Finder > Applications > Utilities
* In Terminal, paste the following: defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
* Press return
* Hold the ‘Option/alt’ key, then right click on the Finder icon in the dock and click Relaunch.

Once you done this. Open unity->Unity->Preferences->External tools

In that find SDK path option, click browse, then drag the “sdk” folder which you just opened above in Finder…

Done…

If its still giving error then consider below case:

Sometimes Unity won’t recognise Android Studio’s sdk tools and gives error and ask you to again set the path.

To solve this, download separate sdk tools from Google.
Link : https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip

Once you download the “tools” folder.
Then copy it and replace it in “/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk”.

And try again…

I know this is not written well…but if you are struggling a lot ..if will just give you an correct hint. I struggled a lot for this issue…so wanted to help you all.
Thank you…